# check/uncheck rows by value in an html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `HTML` table as illustrated below.  It is generated via `PHP` from a `MySQL` database.  Using Jquery and JScript, I am able to "check all the rows" or "uncheck all the rows" using the box marked "A".

[image]

[Example Screenshot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBVzu.jpg)

What I am trying to achieve is the ability to select all rows in which a specific value (e.g. Female) occurs in a specific column, by checking the appropriate box (e.g. the one marked "B").  Removing the check mark from this Box would remove all the check marks from the "Female" rows.

The ability to do this is important because the actual table contains 3500+ rows.

Comment: Picture is good to show the problem but you nave not included any code to allow anyone to help you. Please follow the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve,

Comment: @Jack refer my work below

Comment: thats absolutely what I am looking for but do you able to provide more simple solution for me hence that became more compliated with my current script

Comment: I have found Table plug-in for jQuery (named "datatables") which can also provide so prompt accordingly, adding this comment to reveal for others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below.

In my example I sorted only by gender, In order to filter by location and more you can add them in data attribute and modify jquery accordingly

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
   $('table tr').find('td:eq(0) input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('div>input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).attr('checked', false)
   var gender = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   $('table tr[data-sex="'+gender+'"').find('td:eq(0) input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Gender</td>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Hobby</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-sex="female">
                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Ancy</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>NY</td>
    <td>Footbal</td>
   </tr>
            <tr data-sex="male">
                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Anto</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>CA</td>
    <td>Chess</td>
   </tr>
            <tr data-sex="female">
                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Pamela</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>NY</td>
    <td>Basket Ball</td>
   </tr>
            <tr data-sex="male">
                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>William</td>
    <td>Male</td>
    <td>LA</td>
    <td>Sleeping</td>
   </tr>
            <tr data-sex="female">
                <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>monica</td>
    <td>Female</td>
    <td>NY</td>
    <td>Eating</td>
   </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Male">&nbsp;Male
  <input type="checkbox" value="Female">&nbsp;Female
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Server side (php) output the markup for the checkbox with:

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-gender="female" />
```

then client side, when someone ticks the "female" checkbox, do this:

```
var checkedState = ... //get state to set,

$('.tableClassName input[checkbox]').each(function(index, item) {
  var jqItem = $(item);
  if(jqItem.data('gender') === 'female') {
    jqItem.attr('checked', checkedState);
  }
})
```